# Get columnt value and the index value from a Python Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

my DataFrame looks like this:

```
                 Open       High        Low      Close  Volume
Date                                                          
2021-08-17  77.120003  77.199997  77.120003  77.199997      49
```

How to get the value of date `2021-08-17` and `77.199997` as string in python?

Comment: `df.loc['2021-08-17','Open'].astype(str)`?

Comment: No, because I don't know the Date value.

Comment: `df.iloc[0,1].astype(str)`?

Comment: It doesn't work KeyError: 0

Comment: `iloc` not `loc`.  `iloc[0,1]` should work along as your dataframe has atleast one row and two columns.

Comment: Why 77.19997 do you know the column is 'high' or do you just want the max value on that row?

Comment: Ok, cool, it works for the amount 'Close' but how can I get the date value? It's probably a index or something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your `DataFrame` :

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from io import StringIO

>>> df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume
2021-08-17,77.120003,77.199997,77.120003,77.199997,49"""))
>>> df = df.set_index('Date')
>>> df
            Open        High        Low         Close       Volume
Date                    
2021-08-17  77.120003   77.199997   77.120003   77.199997   49
```

We can use `astype` to change the format to `str` like so :

```py
>>> df = df.reset_index()
>>> df[['Date', 'High']] = df[['Date', 'High']].astype(str)
```

Then, we can have access to the `Date` using :

```py
>>> df['Date'].values[0]
```

And if you want to keep the `Date` in index :

```py
>>> df = df.set_index('Date')
'2021-08-17'
```

In that case, we have access to the `Date` using :

```py
>>> df.index.values[0]
'2021-08-17'
```

Comment: Ok, but how I get the value of the index for example '2021-08-17' from the row?

Comment: You can have access to the date using : `df['Date'].values[0]` if the `Date` is in column.
 If it is in `index`, you can use : `df.index.values[0]`. Hope it helps :) !

Comment: df.index.values[0] has done the job. Thank you!

Comment: Perfect ! I updated the answer with those to complete it.